# solve $x^y-y^x=xy^2-19,$ $x,y\in\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

I have been struggling to solve this exercise but with no result:

$$x^y-y^x=xy^2-19,$$ $x,y\in{\mathbb Z}$

I have started to think it has no solutions at all. I have no idea how to solve it so I was wondering if anyone could be so kind to help?

Edit, William C. Jagy

Graphed on actual paper.
In the first quadrant, the zero set is two curves, one with vertical and horizontal asymptotes, one with vertical and slanted asymptotes. It follows, easily enough, that there are finitely many integer solutions in the first quadrant.

[image]

Comment: $x=1$ and $y=4$ is a solution

Comment: Are you trying to solve for $x$? Or integer solutions or what?

Comment: find x,y that satisfies the equation

Comment: Just draw a picture with numerical points. One is $x=y=19^{1/3}.$ Where did you get this problem?

Comment: Infinite $x,y$ satisfy the equation...  You've simply defined a curve. What do you want to so with it?

Comment: Other integer solutions include (1,-5) and  (2,3) and (2,7)

Comment: I have no idea....my teacher wants us to solve it. In integer does it have more than one solution but how can I show that has more than one solution?

Comment: @alana I already listed 3 more....

Comment: Is there any way that shows it has infinite solutions in Z?

Comment: Is there any way to get you to get some graph paper and carefully draw a picture, at least in the first quadrant??? https://www.printablepaper.net/category/graph

Comment: how am i supposed to graph x^y-y^x-x*y^2? i tried https://graphsketch.com/  but it gives me errors

Comment: I drew a graph myself and pasted that into your question. I did not use any graphing software, but I did use a programmable scientific calculator that can numerically solve an equation in one variable if given endpoints between which a solution must lie.

Comment: @WillJagy Why not infinitely many integer solutions on the slanted asymptote?

Comment: @Did You cannot have $x=y$ unless $x=y= 19^{1/3}$ because the function set to zero is $x^2 - y^2 - x y^2 + 19.$ If $x=y$ we must have $x y^2 = 19.$ Then, more detailed inequalities than I indicated (or have worked out in detail) will give $x < y < x+1$ along the slanted asymptote.

Comment: @WillJagy True, I missed that (and probably $x-y\to0$ along the slanted asymptote...).

Comment: @Did, yes, I agree about the difference going to zero. Same thing with the other asymptote rays. I don't see that much can be done about a graph with either $x$ or $y$ negative real, although there is at least one such integer solution $(1,-5)$

Comment: @alana By the way the best free online graphing calculator is Desmos Graphing Calculator https://www.desmos.com/calculator It graphs this equation no problem

Comment: @Ovi What is *unkind* here (unless having several experts trying to get you to a solution is)? Please be specific.

Comment: @Ovi Downvotes and putting questions on hold are made exactly for that. Together with being put on hold, comes a paragraph of explanations about how to improve the question. *Even a beginner* can read it and try to follow its recommendations. The OP did not, at any time. And, as mentioned before, the OP received advice from several experts in the comments -- to which their reaction has been substandard (asking for solutions after some were given... o well!). So much so that Will ended up adding himself to the question the diagram the OP ...

Comment: ... was suggested to draw but could not be led to bother drawing themselves. :-( Who is being unkind to whom here, I wonder.

Comment: @Did My apologies, I have deleted my comments

Comment: Except for $(x,y)=(1,-5)$, every solution $(x,y)$ has $x,y>0$.

Answer (score 1):

**Observation 1:** *The unique integral solution $(x,y)$ without $x,y>0$ is $(1,-5)$.*

*Proof.* It is easy to check that $x\neq0$ and $y\neq0$. If $x,y<0$ then $-1\leq x^y,y^x\leq1$ and so $-2\leq x^y-y^x\leq2$. But $x,y<0$ also implies $xy^2-19<-19$, a contradiction. If $x<0$ and $y>0$ then
$$y^x=x^y-xy^2+19,$$
is an integer, and so $y=1$. Then $1=19$, a contradiction. Similarly, if $x>0$ and $y<0$ then
$$x^y=y^x+xy^2-19,$$
is an integer, so $x=1$. Then $y^2+y-20=0$, so $y=-5$.$\hspace{20pt}\square$

From here on we will consider only *positive* $x$ and $y$.

**Proposition 2:** *If $z>y>x>e$ then $x^z-z^x>x^y-y^x>0$.*

*Proof.* This is an elementary exercise in calculus; let $f_x(y):=x^y-y^x$ so that
$$f_x'=\ln(x)x^y-xy^{x-1},$$
and note that $\frac{y}{\ln{y}}$ and $\frac{y-1}{\ln{y}}$ are strictly increasing for $y>e$ because their derivatives
$$\frac{\ln{y}-1}{(\ln{y})^2}
\qquad\text{ and }\qquad
\frac{y(\ln{y}-1)+1}{y(\ln{y})^2},$$
are positive for $y>e$. We see that for $x,y>e$ we have $\ln{x},\ln{y}>0$ and so
$$y>x
\quad\implies\quad
\frac{y}{\ln{y}}>\frac{x}{\ln{x}}
\quad\implies\quad
y\ln{x}>x\ln{y}
\quad\implies\quad
x^y-y^x>0.$$
Moreover, by the same argument we see that
$$y>x
\quad\implies\quad
\frac{y-1}{\ln{y}}>\frac{x-1}{\ln{x}}
\quad\implies\quad
x^{y-1}>y^{x-1}
\quad\implies\quad
\ln(x)x^y-xy^{x-1}>0,$$
which shows that $f_x'(y)>0$, from which the proposition follows.$\hspace{20pt}\square$

For each integer $x$ we want to find the positive integral zeros of
$$g_x(y):=x^y-y^x-xy^2+19.$$

**Proposition 3:** *If $x$ and $y$ are integers with $y>x\geq 4$ then $g_x(y)>0$.*

*Proof.* By Proposition 2 it suffices to show that $g_x(x+1)>0$, where
$$g_x(x+1)=x^{x+1}-(x+1)^x-x(x+1)^2+19.$$
For $x=4$ we find that indeed $g_4(5)=318>0$, and setting $h(x):=g_x(x+1)$ we find that
\begin{eqnarray*}
h'&=&x^x(x(\ln(x)+1)+1)-(x+1)^{x-1}((x+1)\ln(x+1)+x)-(3x^2+4x+1)\\
&=&x^{x-1}\left(x^2(\ln(x)+1)+x-\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^{x-1}((x+1)\ln(x+1)+x)\right)-(3x^2+4x+1)\\
&>&x^{x-1}\left(x^2(\ln(x)+1)+x-ex(\ln(x+1)+\frac{x}{x+1})\right)-(3x^2+4x+1)\\
&>&x^{x-1}\left(x^2(\ln(x)+1)+x-ex(\ln(x+1)+1)\right)-(3x^2+4x+1),\\
\end{eqnarray*}
so in particular for $x\geq4$ it follows
$$h'(x)>2x^{x-1}-(3x^2+4x+1)>0,$$
which implies that indeed $g_x(y)>0$ for all $y>x$ if $x\geq4$.
$\hspace{20pt}\square$

**Observation 4:** *If $g_x(y)=0$ then either $x\leq3$ or $y\leq2$.*

*Proof.* Proposition 3 shows that if $x\geq4$ then $y\leq x$. If $y\geq3$ then by Proposition 2 we have
$$g_x(y)=x^y-y^x-xy^2+19\leq-xy^2+19<-4e^2+19<0,$$
so $g_x(y)\neq0$, a contradiction, so then $y\leq2$.$\hspace{20pt}\square$

At this point we can simply check the remaining cases:

1. If $y=1$ then $g_x(y)=g_x(1)=18$, yielding no solutions.
2. If $y=2$ then for $x>4$ we have
   $$g_x(2)=x^2-2^x-4x+19<x^2-2^x<0,$$
   and a quick check shows that $x\in\{1,2,3,4\}$ yields no solutions.
3. If $x=1$ then $y=4$ as then
   $$g_1(y)=20-y-y^2=-(y-4)(y+5).$$
4. If $x=2$ then for $y\geq8$ we have
   $$g_2(y)=2^y-3y^2+19>0,$$
   and a quick check shows that only $y=3$ and $y=7$ yield solutions.
5. If $x=3$ then for $y\geq5$ we have
   $$g_3(y)=3^y-y^3-3y^2+19>0,$$
   and a quick check shows that $y\in\{1,2,3,4\}$ yields no solutions.

We conclude that the full set of integral solutions $(x,y)$ is 
$$\{(1,-5),\ (1,4),\ (2,3),\ (2,7)\}.$$